# Proper way of receiving and updating data from server in JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, server

I have a Java server thread which retrieves data from a database and sends them to my client. The main client GUI is represented by a `JTabbedPane` and I want every tab (which are `JPanel`s) to receive their own data and show them (for example home panel, purchases panel, profile panel etc).

What I did is to pass the ObjectInput/Output stream to every panel and let him receive data and update them itself by calling the `getAndSet` method on the panel object from the main class (see below). Is that the correct way of doing that?

Here's an example of one of my panels

```
public class PurchasesPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private static final String PANEL_ID = "purchases";

    public PurchasesPanel(ObjectInputStream input, ObjectOutputStream output) {
        this.output = output;
        this.input = input;
        createGUI();
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        //Impostazione del layout e creazione della tabella
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void getAndSetTableModel() {
        try {
            output.writeUTF(PANEL_ID);
            output.flush();

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) input.readObject();
            table.setModel(model);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Si è verificato un errore con il pannello riepilogo acquisti. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the object is received from the server you need to make sure that the GUI is updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This can be done by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Read the section from the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.